# Getting Messages even though it has been disabled for years

Tags: icloud, messages, sms, messages-in-icloud

I just received a text in iMessage on my mac. This is quite surprising, as I haven't owned an iPhone since 2014, and I subsequently disabled iMessage on all the macs I have owned since. As can also be seen in the screenshot. "Aktiver Meldinger i iCloud" is Norwegian and means "Activate Messages in iCloud".

So, given that background, how is it that I suddenly receive messages that would otherwise be sent as SMS?

[image: dialogue showing in imessage]

Answer (score 2):

You need to sign out (Logg av) of iMessage.

Messages in iCloud is a syncing service (keeps deleted/received messages in sync across all your deivces) and doesn't affect ability to send or receive iMessages.

Comment: Oh, I thought that the button that says "Logg av" (Logout) would sign me out of all iCloud/Apple services? I still want to be logged into the App Store, iCloud, etc.

Comment: Nope, it will only sign you out of iMessage (and possibly FaceTime but I believe they're separate)